# Group overlapping dates into a single row

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table that contains events for patients. The events table has the following columns:

- `encounter_id` (event id)
- `patient`
- `start_date`
- `end_date`

Events can overlap.
This is a sample of the table:

| ENCOUNTER_ID | PATIENT | START_DATE | END_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Patient1 | 2022-01-01 01:00:00.000 | 2022-01-10 01:00:00.000 |
| 1 | Patient1 | 2022-01-02 01:00:00.000 | 2022-01-05 01:00:00.000 |
| 2 | Patient1 | 2022-01-20 01:00:00.000 | 2022-01-30 01:00:00.000 |
| 3 | Patient1 | 2022-01-09 01:00:00.000 | 2022-01-15 01:00:00.000 |
| 4 | Patient2 | 2022-01-01 01:00:00.000 | 2022-01-01 02:00:00.000 |
| 5 | Patient2 | 2022-01-02 01:00:00.000 | 2022-01-02 02:00:00.000 |
| 6 | Patient2 | 2022-01-03 01:00:00.000 | 2022-01-03 02:00:00.000 |

I want to group events that overlap for a given patient into a single event.
The final result should be:

| ENCOUNTER_ID | PATIENT | START_DATE | END_DATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | Patient1 | 2022-01-01 01:00:00.000 | 2022-01-15 01:00:00.000 |
| 1 | Patient1 | 2022-01-20 01:00:00.000 | 2022-01-30 01:00:00.000 |
| 2 | Patient2 | 2022-01-01 01:00:00.000 | 2022-01-01 02:00:00.000 |
| 3 | Patient2 | 2022-01-02 01:00:00.000 | 2022-01-02 02:00:00.000 |
| 4 | Patient2 | 2022-01-03 01:00:00.000 | 2022-01-03 02:00:00.000 |

I attached a graph in case it helps.

Top is what I have, bottom is what I want to achieve

[image: I attached a graph in case it helps.]

Basically, `patient 1` has three events that overlap.

- encounter 0 with encounter 1
- encounter 0 with encounter 3

The final event will have the min(start_date) and max(end_date) of all the events that overlap for a given patient.

Some sample code (Snowflake) to create the sample table from the post:

```
select
    index as encounter_id,
    to_char(get(k.value, 0)) as patient,
    to_timestamp(get(k.value, 1)) as start_date,
    to_timestamp(get(k.value, 2)) as end_date
from
table(flatten(
    ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(
        ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('Patient1', '2022-01-01 01:00:00.000', '2022-01-10 01:00:00.000'),
        ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('Patient1', '2022-01-02 01:00:00.000', '2022-01-05 01:00:00.000'),
        ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('Patient1', '2022-01-20 01:00:00.000', '2022-01-30 01:00:00.000'),
        ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('Patient1', '2022-01-09 01:00:00.000', '2022-01-15 01:00:00.000'),
        ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('Patient2', '2022-01-01 01:00:00.000', '2022-01-01 02:00:00.000'),
        ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('Patient2', '2022-01-02 01:00:00.000', '2022-01-02 02:00:00.000'),
        ARRAY_CONSTRUCT('Patient2', '2022-01-03 01:00:00.000', '2022-01-03 02:00:00.000')
        ))) k
```

I tried to join the table to itself but this only helps creating pairs of overlaping events, but it's hard to encode the rule: "If event A and B overlap and A and C overlap, then A,B,C is the full overlap".

Answer (score 1):

This may work for you (or at least give you a good starting point). I can't guarantee that it works for every possible scenario of overlapping/non-overlapping date ranges. You might also ne able to consolidate some of the CTEs together but at the moment they illustrate the logical steps I went through when writing this:

```
with prev_data as (
select *
,min(start_date) over (partition by patient order by start_date rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) min_start_preceding
,max(end_date) over (partition by patient order by start_date rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) max_end_preceding
from encounters
),
overlap1 as (
select *
,case when start_date between min_start_preceding and max_end_preceding or end_date between min_start_preceding and max_end_preceding
      then 'Y' else 'N' end overlap
from prev_data
),
overlap2 as (
select *
,case when lead(overlap) over (partition by patient order by start_date) = 'Y' then 'Y' else overlap end as overlap2
from overlap1
),
group_assign as (
select *
,CONDITIONAL_CHANGE_EVENT(overlap2 = 'Y') OVER (ORDER BY patient, start_date) group_num
from overlap2
)
select patient, encounter_id, start_date, end_date, group_num
from group_assign
where overlap2 = 'Y'
order by patient, start_date
;
```